# Magento 2.3 extra whitespace and lines

Tags: helper

done a ton of searching, found some similar issues but nothing that could lead me to a solution.  I'm running the Magetique theme on Magento 2.3.  On my homepage, I have 2 of the Featured Products widgets with manual products.  I'm getting some strange whitespace and a line above these widgets.  I'm trying to figure out how to remove them because it adds some wasted space on the page that really breaks the flow.  Any advice?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be able to control them with CSS.

Comment: That's what I was hoping but....where do I find the CSS that controls them?  Thank you!

Comment: You should get help with theme builder. Usually, CSS are in each module. More reading here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've found the css files, wouldn't there be a css file that controls the layout of the featured products block that I can just modify and upload?  Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way, but the block gets its style creating that line from somewhere, I just need to find that style and remove it.

Comment: I was hoping this was an easy question for the group, I know there's a lot of Magento developers on here.

Comment: It will be hard for any developer to look into your theme and give you the answer. You should contact your theme developer and they will guide you for the solution. Each theme has diff implementation.